# How do I use npm to install and run packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am attempting to use `npm` to install a `json` validator (`jsonlint`). I installed `npm` using the package manager:

> sudo apt-get install npm

Then I tried to install `jsonlint` using the command

> sudo npm install jsonlint

Which produced a bunch of outputs ending with

```
jsonlint@1.6.2 node_modules/jsonlint
├── nomnom@1.8.1 (underscore@1.6.0, chalk@0.4.0)
└── JSV@4.0.2
```

According to [the documentation for jsonlint](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsonlint) I should now be able to simply run the `jsonlint` command, but I get an error instead:

quant@OptiPlex-990:~$ jsonlint
The program 'jsonlint' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install python-demjson

Clearly the installed package is not being recognised. In this case it looks like the suggested ubuntu package probably does the same task, but I am interested in getting npm to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `jsonlint` from the command line anywhere on your system you'll need to install globally.

```
$ sudo npm install -g jsonlint
```

Without the `-g` flag it will install in the current project directory.

Comment: So the package is installed and now how do we use it? Specifically use it as a module for angular.